# CSV Bulk Upload to complete action after successfully uploaded

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP upload page to bulk upload to the MySQL database.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. After the CSV file has successfully uploaded, I want to run a new action for each row/line of the CSV file.

Below is my upload PHP script;

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

$filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];    
 if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
 {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
      while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
       {
          require('../config.php');
            $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
                  if ($conn->connect_error) {
                      die("Database connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                  }
         $sql = "INSERT INTO `cases` (`case_id`, `clt_title`, `clt_first`, `clt_last`, `clt_add`, `clt_add2`, `clt_add3`, `clt_town`, `clt_county`, `clt_postcode`, `clt_ni`, `clt_dob`, `clt_tel`, `clt_email`, `case_type`, `case_cost`, `case_premium`, `case_term`, `case_source`, `case_drawdown`, `case_redemption`, `case_status`, `case_claim`, `case_incident`, `opp_name`, `opp_add`, `opp_add2`, `opp_add3`, `opp_town`, `opp_county`, `opp_post`, `sol_id`, `sol_ref`, `fund_id`, `invest_id`, `loan_balance`, `prem_charge`, `prem_start`, `up_prem`, `def_prem`, `capcov_prem`, `case_owner`, `received`)
               values ('".$getData[0]."',   '".$getData[1]."',  '".$getData[2]."',  '".$getData[3]."',  '".$getData[4]."',  '".$getData[5]."',  '".$getData[6]."',  '".$getData[7]."',  '".$getData[8]."',  '".$getData[9]."',  '".$getData[10]."', '".$getData[11]."', '".$getData[12]."', '".$getData[13]."', '".$getData[14]."', '".$getData[15]."', '".$getData[16]."', '".$getData[17]."', '".$getData[18]."', '".$getData[19]."', '".$getData[20]."', '".$getData[21]."', '".$getData[22]."', '".$getData[23]."', '".$getData[24]."', '".$getData[25]."', '".$getData[26]."', '".$getData[27]."', '".$getData[28]."', '".$getData[29]."', '".$getData[30]."', '".$getData[31]."', '".$getData[32]."', '".$getData[33]."', '".$getData[34]."', '".$getData[35]."', '".$getData[36]."', '".$getData[37]."', '".$getData[38]."', '".$getData[39]."', '".$getData[40]."', '".$getData[41]."', '".$getData[42]."')";
          
               $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!isset($result))
    {
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
          alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
          window.location = \"../../admin/cases.php?ct=%\"
          </script>";    
    }
    else {
        echo header("Location: http://example.com/fpdf.php?ct=$id");;
    }
       }
  
       fclose($file);  
 }
```

After this upload is complete, I would like to run another PHP script which is held in another file. I tried to run `header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");` but it's not working correctly.

Edit: The next action would be to create a pdf using FPDF, I have the FPDF File set up and working correctly but this is currently a manual process.

Comment: Please use prepared statements, read up on sql injection, Your code would break with the wrong character appearing in the csv file. You are also printing a successful imported on every line, that's a lot of alerts to push to the client if you have a 1000 line csv file. Ideally you'd run a callback there of what you want to execute, and post a positive result, or an array with a summary back to the client, to state which lines were succesful, and which failed.

Comment: "I want to run a new action "...what kind of action? Be specific about what you want, and what problem you're having in trying to implement it.

Comment: The next action to run will be an fpdf document generation, I have also amended original post.